# Magento module working local but not on server

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I've written for Magento 1.9.x a custom module.
Local it is workin great, but it's not being loaded on the server... it look like the module is not loaded.

I want to override customer AccountController and Helper/Data from customer.

Can anyone find an error in the files? Thanks!

I already cleared cache in magento and in /var/cache but with no effect

This are my Files:

/app/etc/modules/Org_RestLogin.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<config>
    <modules>
         <Org_RestLogin>
              <active>true</active> 
              <codePool>local</codePool> 
              <depends>
                  <Mage_Customer /> <!-- Make sure, this is loaded first -->
              </depends>
         </Org_RestLogin>
    </modules>
 </config>
```

/app/code/local/org/RestLogin/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Org_RestLogin>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </Org_RestLogin>
    </modules>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <customer>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <org_restlogin before="Mage_Customer">Org_RestLogin</org_restlogin>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </customer>
        </routers>
    </frontend>

    <global>
       <helpers>
          <customer>
              <rewrite>
                  <data>Org_RestLogin_Customer_Helper_Data</data>
             </rewrite>
          </customer>
       </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

/app/code/local/org/RestLogin/controllers/AccountController.php

```
<?php
require_once 'Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php';

class Org_RestLogin_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController {
    //my custom methods
}
```

/app/code/local/org/RestLogin/Customer/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php
class Org_RestLogin_Customer_Helper_Data extends Mage_Customer_Helper_Data
{
    /**
     * Check whether customers registration is allowed
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isRegistrationAllowed() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any file permissions set on live server?
Have you check is your module showing in admin section ?

Comment: In admin section the module is showing. File permissions are also correct

Comment: is your local and live server using same magento version  ?

Comment: They are using the same magento version: 1.9.2.3

Comment: is the compilation mode disabled or enabled ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
It was a typo in the folder... "org" should be "Org"